# Working with default path

Tags: java, image, path, resources, embedded-resource

Okay guys, I made one research and I found nothing to exemplify correctly that I did this and to not post this as someone lazy. My problem is:

I have one image on the rsc folder of my project. I can acess it from a full path name:

```
C:\Users\Victor\workspace\SHST\rsc\image.jpg
```

But, I need to move this folder in future to another desktop and 'course I can't change for every variable the Main path `"C:\Users\Victor\workspace\"`. I tried to thing about environment variables but even though I swear  I found nothing. I know there is a way to do this and it's not so hard as it's seems, that's why I can't realize I found nothing about it. Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image into `C:\Users\Victor\workspace\SHST\res\` folder in your project and load the image file by call `res/image.jpg`. Than, anywhere you'll replace your project, it should being loaded.

Comment: Incredibly awesome. Epic easy. I tryed things like "~rsc/" ":/rsc" and so on but nothing worked out. Ty!!

Comment: Given this is an application resource, it is likely to become an [tag:embedded-resource] by time of deployment.  As such, using a `File` or a file path will ***not*** work.  For a more robust way to load such things, see the answer by resueman.